# How to to Use Reflection in C# to Execute Method by name?

Tags: c#, function, reflection, invoke, instance-variables

I Want to use Reflection to execute my function(Which name is GetAverage,With no parameter)
And this function is in class by name of Gold.

I Use This Code :

```
string MyFunction = "GetAverages";
Type type = typeof(MyGoldClass);
MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod(MyFunction);
int res = (int)info.Invoke(type,null);
res += 3;
```

But it do not work and Make instance Error Which i do not know what that is.
ATTENTION MyFunction Is a Public Function In Gold Class.And i Want Calling and executing This in Other C# Page.

Comment: is GetAverages  a static method ? if not you need to make a instance of your object first

Comment: Also...Is it called GetAverage or GetAverages? There seems to be an inconsistency in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string MyFunction = "GetAverages";
MethodInfo mi;

mi = typeof(MyGoldClass).GetMethod(MyFunction);
int res = (int)mi.Invoke(new MyGoldClass(), null);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your method is `static` try this

```
int res = (int)info.Invoke(null, null);
```

If it is `instance` method try this

```
int res = (int)info.Invoke(instanceOfMyGoldClass, null);
```

where `instanceOfMyGoldClass` is a valid instancce of `MyGoldClass`

Refer [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) for more info

If this doesn't help post your method definition/signature. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your method is public:

```
string MyFunction = "GetAverages";
Type type = typeof(MyGoldClass);
MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod(MyFunction);
int res = (int)info.Invoke(new MyGoldClass(), null);
res += 3;
```

Take a look at [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the Invoke method takes 2 parameters

1st-the object on which the method should be invoked

2nd-the arguments passed to the method

if the method is "static", it can not be called using an object so use

```
int res=(int)info.Invoke(null,null);
```

if the method is non-static, an object of MyGoldClass should be passed to invoke the method so use

```
int res=(int)info.Invoke(new MyGoldClass(),null);
```